# Matlab 3D plot with 2 variable different range

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, equation

Plot this graph using Matlab with function as follows:

R(t1,t2) = 0 ........ t1<0 or t2<0

```
       = 1 ...... t1>T and t2>T

       = min(t1,t2)/T , otherwise
```

T is time interval

Comment: It is a plot which has values varying for x and y axis and z varing according to that.. can anyone please explain how to plot this varying range in Matlab.. can I use if else to move along x and y axis and give z output depending on this condition.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/2-and-3d-plots.html

Answer (score 0):

I Finally solved that using linspace to form a grid and plot the equation using if condition.